# Minimize objective function using limfit.minimize in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

I am having a problem with package `lmfit.minimize` minimization procedure. Actually, I could not create a correct objective function for my problem.

**Problem definition**

- My function: `yn = a_11*x1**2 + a_12*x2**2 + ... + a_m*xn**2`,where `xn`- unknowns, `a_m` - 
                coefficients. n = 1..N, m = 1..M
- In my case, `N=5` for  `x1,..,x5` and `M=3` for `y1, y2, y3`.

I need to find the `optimum: x1, x2,...,x5` so that it can satisfy the `y`

**My question:**

- Error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,5)`.
- Did I create the objective function of my problem properly in Python?

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Parameters, minimize

def func(x,a):
    return np.dot(a, x**2)

def residual(pars, a, y):
    vals = pars.valuesdict()
    x = vals['x']
    model = func(x,a)
    return y - model

def main():
    # simple one: a(M,N) = a(3,5)
    a = np.array([ [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ],
                   [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ],
                   [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ] ])
    # true values of x
    x_true = np.array([10, 13, 5, 8, 40])
    # data without noise
    y = func(x_true,a)

    #************************************
    # Apriori x0
    x0 = np.array([2, 3, 1, 4, 20])
    fit_params = Parameters()
    fit_params.add('x', value=x0)

    out = minimize(residual, fit_params, args=(a, y))
    print out
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I get another error with your code `ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

Comment: @Saullo . I got again the same error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (3,5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly using `scipy.optimize.minimize()` the code below solves this problem. Note that with more points `yn` you will tend to get the same result as `x_true`, otherwise more than one solution exists. You can minimize the effect of the ill-constrained optimization by adding boundaries (see the `bounds` parameter used below).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def residual(x, a, y):
    s = ((y - a.dot(x**2))**2).sum()
    return s

def main():
    M = 3
    N = 5
    a = np.random.random((M, N))
    x_true = np.array([10, 13, 5, 8, 40])
    y = a.dot(x_true**2)

    x0 = np.array([2, 3, 1, 4, 20])
    bounds = [[0, None] for x in x0]
    out = minimize(residual, x0=x0, args=(a, y), method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=bounds)
    print(out.x)
```

If `M>=N` you could also use `scipy.optimize.leastsq` for this task:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def residual(x, a, y):
    return y - a.dot(x**2)

def main():
    M = 5
    N = 5
    a = np.random.random((M, N))
    x_true = np.array([10, 13, 5, 8, 40])
    y = a.dot(x_true**2)

    x0 = np.array([2, 3, 1, 4, 20])
    out = leastsq(residual, x0=x0, args=(a, y))
    print(out[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. Why not with `lmfit`, Is something wrong with`lmfit`?  My problem is really M<<N (higly ill-posed). Is it still possible in this case? :)

Comment: @Spider yes, using the first option with `scipy.optimize.minimize()`

Comment: How can avoid 'minues' values in the output? For me it should be `+`. What would you think?

Comment: @Spider see the edits... I've included how to use the parameter `bounds` in order to add constraints...